# Machine friendly ansible output

Tags: shell, ansible

I would like to run ansible playbook in a way that it outputs in a machine friendly format, that means something I can parse somehow.

By default ansible playbook provides output like this:

```
ansible-playbook playbooks/test.yml 

PLAY [all] *********************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [server]
ok: [foo]
```

And it isn't even guaranteed to keep this style for output forever. I need to be able to parse the output, is there a way to get the output of playbook in JSON or XML?

Answer (score 3):

You can use python [Ansible Callbacks](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_plugins.html#callbacks). You just need to define where your callbacks are located and you can do all sorts of stuff with structured data.

Example ansible.cfg:

```
[defaults]
callback_plugins = ~/your/path/to/callbacks
```

And write a very simple callback (`log.py`):

```
class CallbackModule(object):
    CALLBACK_VERSION = 2.0
    CALLBACK_TYPE = 'notification'
    CALLBACK_NAME = 'logs'
    CALLBACK_NEEDS_WHITELIST = True

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        if item.startswith('runner_on_'):
            def fn(*args, **kwargs):
                self.on_runner(item[len('runner_on_'):], *args, **kwargs)

            return fn

        if item.startswith('v2_') and self.hasattr(item[len('v2_'):]):
            # Making it compatible with Ansible 1.9 and 2.0 as well
            return self.__getattr__(item[len('v2_'):])

    def on_runner(self, status, host, payload=None, *args, **kwargs):
        # Do something with the parameters here
        # status is for example on of ['ok', 'changed', 'failed', 'skipped']
        # host is the target where it runs
        # payload is a dict with various parameters depending on the Ansibel module being played

        print self.task.name, status, host, payload
```

There are many hooks in this callback module so you have a lot of option how and when to collect, process, log.

Answer (score 3):

There is no implemented option you can just change. But you can implement it yourself. Since Ansible 2.0 the default output of Ansible is implemented as a callback plugin which can be overridden per Ansible config.

In your Ansible configuration point [stdout_callback](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_configuration.html#stdout-callback) to a custom written plugin. The default callback plugin which is responsible for the output you described can be found [here](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/plugins/callback/default.py).

Alternatively you could as well keep the default output and just create an additional plugin which will directly write to a custom log file which you then later can parse.

If you still use Ansible 1.x you might be able to use [this plugin](https://github.com/petems/ansible-json). In Ansible 2 it is likely not working since the plugin API changed.